# Can a woman go out of her house for essential things during the iddah period after the death of her husband?

Tags: fiqh, iddah

I have heard conflicting views on the subject with some saying

- Incase of first or second divorce, she needs her husband's permission
- Incase of third divorce, she is free

But I'm interested to know what if her husband passed away while still married? What is the ruling in this scenario?

Comment: I think the case of talaq would be more interesting (at least I had never read about it), as the case of death is already covered to some extent in [Can an old widow in her iddat be in her son's nikah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/36281/can-an-old-widow-in-her-iddat-be-in-her-sons-nikah). The answer there wouldn't differ much of the answer of your question.In fact the answer of your question is much easier, nothing hinders her to do so as long as she is back home at night.

Comment: @Medi1Saif jazakallah khair for the clarification. Appreciated!